# The random number of array

Tags: javascript

I want let the random number of array keep refresh，but it didn't work.
Can someone give me some advice?

```
var places=Array(50).fill({}).map(
  function(obj){
    return {
      r: Math.random()*200,
      deg: Math.random()*360,
      opacity: 0
    } 
  }
);
```

Comment: You have many syntax problems with the code shown. Have you looked at the errors it is throwing? Put that code into a linter site like https://jshint.com/ and start debugging the list of issues it generates

Comment: It's also not really clear what you expect as results. This code is really broken. Broken code is not a good substitute for a properly detailed explanation of what you expect

Comment: To @charlietfl  ， I am sorry about that. It is my first code of js. Thanks for your advice...

Comment: OK. I understand and it takes time to learn. Learning how to look for errors and use debugging tools  is just as important s learning to write the code itself. I think you re getting too far ahead of yourself though trying to use map without doing some simpler loops first

Comment: OK, I got it. Thanks for your help again. I will more hard.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you are trying to create array of objects with random values, you can do it:

The [normal while loop](https://www.w3schools.com/js/js_loop_while.asp) method:

```
// declare empty array for later use
const places = []

// iterate 50 times, for each iteration, 
// create and add one object with random values into array
let i = 0
while(i < 50) {
    places.push({
      r: Math.random() * 200,
      deg: Math.random() * 360,
      opacity: 0
  })
  
  i++
}
```

The [Array.from](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/from) method:

```
// first argument define the length of array
// second argument define function to execute for every iteration
const places = Array.from({length: 50}, () => {
 return {
    r: Math.random() * 200,
    deg: Math.random() * 360,
    opacity: 0
  }
})
```